# Error in downgrading the ng-circle-progress version - angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript

I use angular 13 in my project and after I run ng serve, I get this error:

> 0mError:
> node_modules/ng-circle-progress/lib/ng-circle-progress.component.d.ts:218:18
>
> - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires 7 type argument(s).

I also have this error too:

> Error: export 'NgCircleProgressModule' (imported as
> 'NgCircleProgressModule') was not found in 'ng-circle-progress'
> (module has no exports).

When I want to try to change the verion of the ng-circle-progress to 1.6.0, I get this error:

> **npm ERR! errno -4048
> npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Tehranplus_Build\AngularSource\node_modules\ng-circle-progress\node_module**s'

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide a bit more information about your project. Is this a fresh app, or have you made changes? What OS are you on? What version of node/npm? If possible, include a [mre].